Exam class: multicolumn questions, fillwithgrid only in one column
I'm making a test using the exam class, and I want to put 2 questions next to each other. I've previously accomplished this using the multicols environment, but I'm running into issues because I want to use fillwithgrid under one of the questions but I want normal blank space under the other questions. When putting two questions in the multicolumn environment, the fill with grid extends across the entire page, which is not what I'm looking for.
A minimal example:
\documentclass{exam}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\colorgrids
\definecolor{GridColor}{gray}{0.3}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\question[2]{Graph something.}
\fillwithgrid{1.75in}

\question[4]{Calculate something.}
\vspace{\stretch{1}}
\end{multicols}

\end{questions}
\end{document}

This produces:

The issue being that I want the grid only on the left half of the page, not the right side too.

Quick hack: use minipages
\documentclass{exam}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\colorgrids
\definecolor{GridColor}{gray}{0.3}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}

\begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
\question[2]{Graph something.}
\fillwithgrid{1.75in}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
\question[4]{Calculate something.}
\end{minipage}%


\end{questions}
\end{document}



This is exactly what I needed, thank you!

@realtoughkid13 You're welcome!

@realtoughkid13 -- just based on the silly types of misunderstandings I've seen on exams over the years, I suggest this layout is too clever by half, and I recommend not doing this using a columnar layout.

You could redefine the \fillwithgrid macro so it utilises the \columnwidth instead of the \textwidth. This way it will automatically adapt to the current width of the column:
\documentclass{exam}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\colorgrids
\definecolor{GridColor}{gray}{0.3}

\makeatletter
\def\fillwithgrid#1{%
  \begingroup
  \ifhmode
    \par
  \fi
  \hrule height \z@
  \nobreak

  % We first set box0 equal to an \hbox which, when printed, is a
  % square with width and height equal to \gridsize+\gridlinewidth,
  % but which has
  % width equal to \gridsize,
  % height equal to \gridsize, and
  % depth equal to 0pt.
  % When we put multiple copies of it together using \leaders or
  % \cleaders, the right edge will coincide with the left edge of the
  % next box and the bottom edge will coincide with the top edge of
  % the box below it.
  \setlength{\@tempdima}{\gridsize}
  \addtolength{\@tempdima}{\gridlinewidth}
  \setlength{\@tempdimb}{\gridsize}
  \addtolength{\@tempdimb}{-\gridlinewidth}
  \setbox0=\hbox{%
    \rlap{\vrule height \gridsize depth \gridlinewidth width \gridlinewidth}%
    \rlap{\vrule height \gridsize depth -\@tempdimb width \@tempdima}%
    \vrule height 0pt depth \gridlinewidth width \@tempdima
    \llap{\vrule height \gridsize depth \gridlinewidth width \gridlinewidth}%
  }%
  \wd0=\gridsize
  \dp0=0pt
  % Now we set box1 equal to an \hbox containing a single line of
  % copies of box0.  We use \leaders (instead of \cleaders) so that
  % if we use it twice on a page, once with a question and once
  % with a part, the boxes will line up vertically.  We add a kern of
  % \gridlinewidth at the right because the rightmost vertical line
  % appears to the right of where the \leaders command thinks that it
  % appears.
  \setbox1=\hbox to \columnwidth{%
    \color@begingroup
    \if@colorgrids
      \color{GridColor}%
    \fi
    \hskip \@totalleftmargin \leaders\copy0\hfil \kern\gridlinewidth
    \color@endgroup
  }%
  % Finally: We create the grid, using \cleaders: We use \cleaders
  % (rather than \leaders) so that a given vertical space will always
  % produce the same number of lines no matter where on the page it
  % happens to start.  We add a kern of \gridlinewidth because the
  % bottommost horizontal line appears below where the \cleaders
  % command thinks that it appears.
  \cleaders \copy1 \vskip #1 \kern \gridlinewidth \hbox{}%
  \endgroup
}% fillwithgrid

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\question[2]{Graph something.}
\fillwithgrid{1.75in}

\question[4]{Calculate something.}
\vspace{\stretch{1}}
\end{multicols}

\question[2]{Graph something.}
\fillwithgrid{1.75in}

\end{questions}
\end{document}


